# detecting length of pattern in a sequence with lstm in keras

Tags: keras, sequence, lstm, pattern-recognition

I am working on a LSTM network to detect a pit in the road. I have a dataset with the wheelspeed from every wheel of a car. when a pit occured, the next 40 labels are a '1'. All other labels are '0'. This is my model:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64,input_shape=(len(X_train[0]),1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LSTM(64,input_shape=(len(X_train[0]),1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

From this i get some very good predictions:
[Top: predicted, bottom: labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obbEX.png)
Now i want to calculate the length of the discovered sequence aka the pit itself. This is where i am struggling with. I was thinking about using some sort of window. everything outside the window is set equal to 0, everything inside is kept as is. The problem with this solution is that my predictions are wrong. Because i alter the data, the network seems to find a pit even when there is no pit present. Does anyone have an idea how i can find the length of the pit in a different manner?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pits are continuous, instead of predicting each point as pit or not, you can let the network predict the change from normal to pit and pit to normal based on the moving window. This will still be a multi-label classification problem. Now, you can calculate the length of the pit from the points the model predicts changes knowing you start on normal surface.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not possible. A pit can only be detected when it has passed. So labelling at the start of a pit is no option. At this point nothing has been identified yet.